# Jqplot pie chart rendering only lines

Tags: jqplot

am loading jqplot corresponding files dynamically and passed data to the and chart div but at sometimes am getting the graph and some other time am not getting the graph my code as follows i maid an ajax call to get the values and passed to the graph in object st and the output am getting is shown here http://i43.tinypic.com/wcfns0.png please help me function

```
jsFunction3(xyz) {
 jQuery.getCSS = function( url, media )
 {
 jQuery( document.createElement('link') ).attr({ href: url, media: media || 'screen', type: 'text/css', rel: 'stylesheet' }).appendTo('head'); };

 $.getCSS('/redkanproject/plugins/jqplot-0.1/css/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css','print'); 
 $.getScript('/redkanproject/plugins/jqplot-0.1/js/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js', 

function() { }); $.getScript('/redkanproject/plugins/jqplot-0.1/js/jqplot/excanvas.min.js', function() { });
 $.getScript('/redkanproject/plugins/jqplot-0.1/js/jqplot/plugin/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js', function() { }); 

var JSONObject = new Object; 
JSONObject.id =xyz;
 JSONstring = JSON.stringify(JSONObject); 
var url = "${createLink(controller:'page', action:'example4')}"; new Ajax.Request(url, { method:'post', contentType:'application/json', postBody:JSONstring, asynchronous:true, onSuccess: function (res) { 
st=(res.responseJSON)
 x="chart" // this is my div to display chart 
var plot1 = $.jqplot (x, [st], { title: 'Bianual Reviews percentage', grid: {
background:'#834100', shadow: true,borderWidth: 0, borderColor: 'white',shadowDepth: 0}, seriesDefaults: {
 // Make this a pie chart. 
renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer, rendererOptions: { 
// Put datalabels on the pie slices. 
// By default, labels show the percentage of the slice. 
sliceMargin:6,
showDataLabels: true
 }
 },
 legend: { show:true, location: 'e' } } ); 
$(x).bind('jqplotDataClick', function(ev,seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) 
{ alert(" data: "+data); } 
);
 } 
})//ajax }
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You seriously expect someone to help you when you leave the question formatted like that?

Comment: @Mark i edited it neatly please could you help me

Comment: why are you using $.getCSS and $.getScript, why not load the resources jqPlot needs statically.  I think you have a little race condition here.  Retrieve the CSS and JS files via Ajax and at the same time create the plot via Ajax.  Those are all asynchronous requests, there is no guarantee that the JS and CSS will be loaded before the plot call.

Comment: @Mark i checked that all files r loading before the graph drwan, the graph drwaing was done in myX function and the files loading  was done in my Y function

Comment: @Mark i checked that all files r loading before the graph drwan, the graph drwaing was done in myX() function and the files loading  was done in myY() function, here myY() calls the $.getScript files and after a delay am calling my mtX() function to print the graph

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it turned out that I had a global style on the table element which sets the width to 100%. 
eg

```
table{
width:100%
}
```

I changed that to auto and everything displayed correctly

```
table{
width:auto;
}
```

Hope that helps :-)